# Ubuntu (GNOME) default video player name

Tags: gnome, video-player

I want to report a [bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481385/ubuntu-18-04-playing-videos-with-default-player-not-working) with the default video player in Ubuntu.

Based on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html) instructions I need to also know the program name.
On the icon it's named "Videos" but using `ubuntu-bug videos` returns an error that the package isn't installed.
That is the name of the app.
[image]

App Visible on the background using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to trigger an error reporting modal.
That states there's no such app with that name
[image]

Comment: Run the video player, look up name from PID: ls -l /proc/[PID]/exe; OR search installed packages

Comment: The most likely cause of linked 'bug' is from gstreamer1.0-vaapi. Try removing it & see. `sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi`  (- known and previously reported bug

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This isn’t obvious, but the GNOME [Videos](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos) applications is also known as Totem, and the corresponding package is `totem`:

```
ubuntu-bug totem
```

To find this out, the most reliable way, based on an application’s name in the launcher, is to find the corresponding launcher configuration file. Open a terminal, and run

```
grep -r Videos /usr/share/applications
```

This will list `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Totem.desktop`; to find out which package supplies this file, run

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Totem.desktop
```