# 18.04 default video player failure

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, arm, totem

I was excited to boot 18.04.2 on an [Nvidia Nano](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/buy/jetson-nano-devkit) for the first time this morning. After a couple of tries, it finally booted. I tried to play a couple of videos from the NAS, and the device crashes when videos are played in full screen mode.  The `Videos` application will display videos if not in full screen mode.  In this case, **crash means the operating system is halted** and power must be cycled.

## QUESTIONS

1. Is the failure a known issue?
2. Is the failure a software issue?
3. What tests can be performed to diagnose the root cause of the issue?

## UPDATES

[Totem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098203/ubuntu-gnome-default-video-player-name) is the name of the default video player.

To confirm the name based on an application’s name in the launcher, find the corresponding launcher configuration file:

```
grep -r Videos /usr/share/applications
```

This will list `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Totem.desktop`; to find out which package supplies this file, run

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Totem.desktop
```

Attempt to upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade totem
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
totem is already the newest version (3.26.0-0ubuntu6.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb busybox-static cryptsetup-bin dpkg-repack gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 grub-common
  kde-window-manager kinit kio kpackagetool5 kwayland-data kwin-common kwin-data kwin-x11 libdebian-installer4
  libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5 libkf5activities5 libkf5attica5 libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5
  libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5 libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5
  libkf5idletime5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiontlm5
  libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5plasma5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5textwidgets-data
  libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5
  libkscreenlocker5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects11 libkwinglutils11 libkwinxrenderutils11 libqgsttools-p1
  libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5test5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-damage0 os-prober
  python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-icu python3-pam python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-sip
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick2 rdate
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 161 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no package named `videos`, I think you're talking about the default video player with `18.04`. It's not a good player compared to other players on the market.

I'd suggest you try `VLC` which is far superior and would run almost any video format you throw at it, without any configuration needed.

Try

`sudo apt install vlc --install-recommends`

Comment: This is a may very well be the only option if the issue with Totem is not diagnosed and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if this bug is know or if you want to report it on these websites: 
GNOME Gitlab https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/issues
Ubuntu Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem